# How to get the rowid back from an ExecuteOracleNonQuery in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm using an ExecuteOracleNonQuery in C# to INSERT a record into my Oracle database using a stored procedure but can't seem to get the ROWID to return.

In C# ...

```
using (OracleConnection oc= 
    new OracleConnection(AppConfiguration.ConnectionString))
{
    OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand("PKG_TEST.INSERT", oc);
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_Id", allAssets.Id);
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_Description", allAssets.Description);
    OracleString rowId;
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        result = myCommand.ExecuteOracleNonQuery(out rowId);
        allAssets.RowId = rowId.ToString();
    }
    catch(System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
    finally
    {
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
return result;
```

Procedure in Oracle package ...

```
PROCEDURE insert (
  p_id               IN   ALL_ASSETS.id%TYPE,
  p_description      IN   ALL_ASSETS.description%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO ALL_ASSETS
              (id, description)
       VALUES (p_id, p_description);
END insert;
```

Can anyone shed any light on how the ROWID is returned, please?

EDIT - I've now changed the code to be as above but still no ROWID return. Also, only one record is being inserted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you expect it to return a rowid ? No where in the DB end have you asked it to, and procedure isn't going to return a ROWID and wouldn't know which one to return anyway.

Automatically returning the ROWID of affected rows can work for INSERT/UPDATE/MERGE and maybe DELETE (though I'm not sure of the point in that case).

You can use 
INSERT INTO ALL_ASSETS (id, description) VALUES (p_id, p_description) RETURNING ROWID INTO v_rowid;

v_rowid would be a variable in the PL/SQL, and you could return it from the database as an additional out parameter, or convert the procedure into a function.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Gary. I've tried passing it back myself as an out param but to no avail (original code posted had this). C# has an out keyword which is used to return the rowid in this instance.

From MSDN:

"ExecuteOracleNonQuery differs from ExecuteNonQuery in that it returns rowid as an output parameter if you are executing an INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statement that affects exactly one row. This allows you to uniquely identify a row in the Oracle database, which can allow you to increase performance in subsequent, related queries."

However, they don't mention how this is returned!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, do you actually need to specify the rowid as an out parameter in your stored procedure?? I thought that ExecuteOracleNonQuery automatically returned it as a c# out variable.

Comment: That's what I thought to, which is why I hadn't originally declared it. However, I still wasn't getting anything back.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the SP is affecting exactly 1 row; the documentation suggests that it might not be returned if not...

Comment: Yeah, I've traced it through and only one record is being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

```
OracleString rowid;
cmd.ExecuteOracleNonQuery(out rowid);
```

Comment: While this code appears to answer the question, a brief explanation of what was missing in the original and how this addresses it would be more helpful.